# How can I make sure a method is only called once by multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, concurrency

I have the following structure:

```
public void someMethod(){  
   //DO SOME STUFF
   try{  
    doSomeProcessing();  
   }  
   catch (Exception e){  
        loadSomeHeavyData();  
        doSomeProcessing();      
   }    
}
```

The method `someMethod` *may* be called concurrently by many threads. The `doSomeProcessing` *may* throw an exception (it is using some data in the backend that could become obsolete).
If an exception is thrown then `loadSomeHeavyData();` does some timeconsuming task that let's say "updates" all the current data and I am able to call `doSomeProcessing();`.
**Problem:** How can I make sure that `loadSomeHeavyData();` is called only **once**? If I put some atomic flag in the entry of `loadSomeHeavyData();` then I can not be sure when this should be cleared.
How can I solve this? Just a note: I can not modify `doSomeProcessing();` as it is an external API and I am using decorator pattern to use it.

Comment: Once *ever*, or just avoiding concurrent calls?

Comment: `How can I make sure that loadSomeHeavyData(); is called only once?` Not very clear. do you want if one thread calls `loadSomeHeavyData`, other threads shouldn'r call it even after exception occurs?

Comment: Why do you want to clear the atomic flag of `loadSomeHeavyData()`? I guess that you just want to load those data once?

Comment: @JonSkeet:I can not avoid concurrent calls.But the exception would be thrown and would like just 1 of the threads to acall the heavy API.

Comment: @Azodious:Either that or somehow other threads "understand" that the heavy API has been already called and data will be refreshed for them as well by the first thread

Comment: One quesiton: When should `loadSomeHeavyData();` be called again? i.e. how do you know that it's time to refresh data again, even if it has been refreshed before.

Comment: @Azodious:Once an exception is thrown and the `loadSomeHeavyData()` has run an exception is not expected unless the user has changed the configuration or data. So not soon

Comment: @Jim: But what would you want to happen if the exception *is* thrown again? It's important to capture all the requirements precisely.

Comment: @JonSkeet:If/when it is thrown again I would like the `loadSomeHeavyData()` to be called by the first thread that is able to call the API.Many threads could get the same exception concurrently but only one would again call `loadSomeHeavyData` all the way

Comment: @Jim: in place of calling `loadSomeHeavyData` in `catch`, put a request to call in a queue. it's a design change but serves your requirement better. check my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `loadSomeHeavyData` method could use a blocking mechanism to make all threads wait until it has finished its update, but only let one of them actually do the update:

```
private final AtomicBoolean updateStarted = new AtomicBoolean();
private final CountDownLatch updateFinished = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void loadSomeHeavyData() {
    if (updateStarted.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        //do the loading
        updateFinished.countDown();
    } else {
        //update already running, wait
        updateFinished.await();
    }
}
```

Note my assumptions:

- you want all the threads to wait until the loading completes so they can call `doSomeProcessing` a second time with updated data
- you only call `loadSomeHeavyData` once, ever - if not you will need to reset the flag and the CountdownLatch (which would then probably not be the most appropriate mechanism).

**EDIT**

Your latest comment indicates that you actually want to call `loadSomeHeavyData` more than once, just not more than once *at a time*.

```
private final Semaphore updatePermit = new Semaphore(1);

public void loadSomeHeavyData() {
    if (updatePermit.tryAcquire()) {
        //do the loading and release updatePermit when done
        updatePermit.release();
    } else {
        //update already running, wait
        updatePermit.acquire();
        //release the permit immediately
        updatePermit.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah!I will need to call `loadSomeHeacyData` again if an exception is thrown at some time later.How could I use your answer in this case?

Comment: @Jim See my edit - you should update your question to be more specific.

Comment: Note: with the second option, it can happen that one thread gets the exception, but by the time it calls loadSomeHeavyData the data has actually been updated and it loads the data again.

Comment: I see what you mean.Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @Jim one trick would be to use an atomicboolean as well and reset it to false after a certain period. And if it true, skip the meethod.

Comment: But now doesn't the issue depend on the time period interval? Should it be too small?Too big?How big?

Comment: @Jim When a load has completed - how much do you want to wait before another load is performed?

Comment: The corner case you mention is e.g. 5 threads get an exception *concurrently* and for some reason due to scheduling thread-5 tries to acquire the semaphore after the data has been reloaded(other threads have already finished).Right?So in this case how would the interval help?It is not clear to me.Can you please explain?

Comment: Please check also here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362427/guarantees-of-atomicreference

Comment: for thread which gets the permit to load the data, what if it throws an exception while loading the data, would it cause the permit is not released? maybe use try finally to release the permit in the finally block.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `synchronized` keyword:

```
public synchronized void someMethod(){  
    //doStuff
}
```

You assure that only one thread enters at a time.

To assure that the method is called only once, there is no special language feature; you could create a static variable of type boolean which is set to true by the first thread entering the method. When calling the method always check that flag:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static boolean calledMyMethod;

    public synchronized void someMethod() {
        if(calledMyMethod) { 
            return;
        } else {
            calledMyMethod = true;
            //method logic
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can not change it to be `synchronized`

Answer (score 1):

```
public void someMethod()
{  
    //DO SOME STUFF
    try
    {  
        doSomeProcessing();  
    }   
    catch (Exception e)
    {   
        loadSomeHeavyData();  // Don't call here but add a request to call in a queue.
                              // OR update a counter
        doSomeProcessing();      
    }
}
```

One of the solutions could be to create a queue in which each thread puts its request to call `loadSomeHeavyData`. when no. of requests reach a threashold, block the execution of `someMethod` and call `loadSomeHeavyData` and clear the queue.

Pseudocode may look like this:

```
int noOfrequests = 0;
public void someMethod()
{
    // block incoming threads here.  
    while(isRefreshHappening);

    //DO SOME STUFF
    try
    { 
        doSomeProcessing();  
    }   
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log the exception
        noOfrequests++;   
    }
}

// Will be run by only one thread
public void RefreshData()
{
    if(noOfrequests >= THRESHOLD)
    {
        isRefreshHappening = true;
        // WAIT if any thread is present in try block of somemethod
        // ...
        loadSomeHeavyData();
        noOfrequests = 0;
        isRefreshHappening = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to add some small snippet for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question you need to load data in an unpredictable but limited time interval. There are three possible ways to do so:
1) You could surround your call to loadSomeHeavyData with an if statement which controls the access to the method.
2) You could change your method to handle the control flow (decision to update or not)
3) Write an update thread and let it do the work for you
The first two alternatives could use an external boolean value or generate a boolean decision by using the timedelta between the last call und the current calling time.
Third alternative would be a timed thread which runs every n seconds/minutes and load the heavy data.

Answer (score 0):

We wrote a library that includes a [utility](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-util-concurrent/wiki/LazyReference%20and%20ResettableLazyReference) lazily load/call a method. It guarantees single usage semantics and preserves any thrown exceptions as you'd expect.

Usage is simple:

```
LazyReference<Thing> heavyThing = new LazyReference<Thing>() {
  protected Thing create() {
    return loadSomeHeavyData();
  }
};

public void someMethod(){  
  //DO SOME STUFF
  try{  
    doSomeProcessing();  
  }  
  catch (Exception e){  
    heavyThing.get();  
    doSomeProcessing();      
  }    
}
```

All threads block on the `get()` and wait for the producer thread (the first caller) to complete.

Comment: Seems to have a lot of dependencies.How could I use this?

Comment: This seems to do what I need, but it seems to need many libraries (google etc)

Comment: It has one dependency on google's guava – we found that every project was already depending on this, and we wanted to use a consistent Function interface. We recently added a Promise that uses guava's ListenableFuture stuff as well. All other dependencies are test (or optional in the case of find-bugs annotations).