# Guarantees of AtomicReference

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

What are the semantics of an `AtomicReference`?
If I do:

`AtomicReference<CustomObject> ref = new AtomicReference<CustomObject>();`

and then I do:

```
public void someMethod(){  
 //do something  

 ref.set(loadNewData());  

}  

private final Sempahore updatePermit = new Sempahore(1);  

private CustomObject loadNewData(){  
     CustomObject obj = null;  
     if (updatePermit.tryAcquire()) {  
        obj = ...; //do the loading and create Object  
        updatePermit.release();  
    } else {  
        //update already running, wait  
        updatePermit.acquire();  
        //release the permit immediately  
        updatePermit.release();  
        obj = ref.get(); //????
    }  
    return obj;    
}
```

Is there a **guarantee** that on line `obj = ref.get(); //????` the `get` will return the **most** fresh version of `CustomObject`?
This is related to the answer of assylias for [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356702/how-can-i-make-sure-a-method-is-only-called-once-by-multiple-threads):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, your code has a race condition which could cause new data to be lost:

1. first caller goes into loadNewData and starts loading new data (has semaphore)
2. second caller cannot get semaphore and waits at acquire
3. first caller finishes loading and releases semaphore (but doesn't return new data yet)
4. second caller acquires semaphore, calls `ref.get()` and gets *old* data
5. first caller returns new data which is passed to `ref.set()`
6. second caller return *old* data which overwrites new data when passed to `ref.set()`

Since `someMethod()` is *always* loading new data and you *always* want callers to wait while new data is loading, all this extra stuff is useless.  just use a simple synchronized block (or Lock) around the whole block and ditch the atomic reference.  according to the linked post, it seems like you only ever want to do this once, so use an initialized flag.

```
private boolean _initialized;

public synchronized void loadLatestData() {
  if(!_initialized) {
      // load latest data ...
      _initialized = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: And the way around this would be to move the `ref.set` inside `loadNewData` before the semaphore `release`.

Comment: @IanRoberts - yes, or just ditch all that nonsense and use a simple lock.

Comment: @jtahlborn I don't think a simple lock would solve the original issue detailed in the linked post. I agree on the race condition though. If 2 threads T1 and T2 call `loadNewData`, T1 should load the data, T2 should wait for the data to be loaded by T1 and exit the method once T1 has finished loading.

Comment: @assylias - i never actually looked at the linked post.  nevertheless, a simple boolean "initialized" flag would solve the "only do this once" problem.  will update.

Comment: @jtahlborn It is actually not a "only do this once" issue. See my comment above (original question in the linked post was unclear).

Comment: @assylias - my latest example code will behave exactly as you specify.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.
`AtomicReference` guarantees publication.

However, there is no guarantee that a different thread won't set it a millisecond later.

Note that if you aren't calling `compareAndSet()`, an `AtomicReference` is no better than a `volatile` field.

Comment: If thread `A` does `updatePermit.release();` is there a guarantee that thread `B` will be able to "see" the value returned from thread `A`?  
I.e. will the `ref` be updated *before* `B` tries to do `get` after releasing the semaphore?

Comment: But I don't need `compareAndSet`

Comment: @Jim: Then you might as well use `volatile` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Reading [JavaDoc of `java.util.concurrent.atomic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html):

> - `get` has the memory effects of reading a `volatile` variable.
> - `set` has the memory effects of writing (assigning) a `volatile` variable.

So the guarantees are: `get()` *always* returns the last value passed to `set()`. It doesn't matter what you do in the meantime, what kind of locks you use, etc. Modifying `volatile` variable (which you effectively do) is guaranteed to be visible by all other threads reading that value.

Comment: If thread `A` does `updatePermit.release();` is there a guarantee that thread `B` will be able to "see" the value returned from thread `A`?  
I.e. will the `ref` be updated *before* `B` tries to do `get` after releasing the semaphore?

Comment: @Jim: semaphore is irrelevant here, read about the `volatile` variable guarantees. Somephores and synchronization is only relevant for *normal* variables.

Comment: Then when would one prefer `AtomicReference` over `volatile`?

Comment: @Jim: If you are only using `get()` and `set()`, there is no real benefit except readability. `atomic*` are useful when you use CAS operations and other high-performance non-blocking methods like `incrementAndGet()`.

Answer (score 1):

Atomic variables (including `AtomicReference`) have the same properties as `volatile` fields, in that they establish a happens-before relation across threads.  If one thread *A* writes a value to a volatile field (or atomic variable) and another thread *B* reads from that same variable then you can't necessarily guarantee whether *B* will or will not see *A*'s change, but you can guarantee that

- **IF** *B* sees the value written by *A*
- **THEN** *B* will also see the results of any writes to *other* fields (volatile and non-volatile) that *A* did before it wrote the volatile field.